# How to fit label according to its content in UItableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have tableview and i have to display products in cell

Products can be single or multiple at indexpath

example :

```
 ["Burger","SandWitch"]
```

so i need to fix my label according to text in tableview .

its not working.check my screenshot

i want that cell height should be according to content of label

check screenshot text is big in label so it is not fix in cell

[image]

how to achieve this ?

Comment: search about dynamic height of `uilabel` according to content and `uitableViewCell` dynamic height ..

Comment: Provide some code which you have implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution: Object-C

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"text";
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    return cell;
}
```

Maybe you need something like that. Swift 3.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let tableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }    

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "some text ;)"
        let cell: CustomTableViewCell

        if let cel = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? CustomTableViewCell {
            cell = cel
        } else {
            cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        }

        cell.labelValue = "what u want"

        return cell
    }
}
```

and you must subclass UITableViewCell:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var labelValue: String? {
        didSet { update() }
    }
    private let label = UILabel()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        install()
    }

    private func install() {
        let padding: CGFloat = 6
        label.textColor = .black
        label.numberOfLines = 5
        //label.font = Fonts.Default(.Normal).getFont(17, forDifferentDevice: false)
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.7
        label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)

        let cnt1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: padding)
        let cnt2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: padding)
        let cnt3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: padding)
        let cnt4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: padding)
        contentView.addConstraints([cnt1, cnt2, cnt3, cnt4])
    }

    private func update() {
        label.text = labelValue
    }

}
```

Comment: second.. moment

Comment: syntax not supported

Comment: Updated to Swift 3.0.
Try again.

Comment: didSet condition is not satisfying

Comment: It can't be helped. Xcode 8. Swift 3. Everything works

Answer (score 0):

with the use of this function you can set the the lable according to text

```
 func heightForView(text:String, #font:UIFont, #width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = text

        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height
    }

    let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20.0)

    var height = heightForView("This is just a load of text", font: font, width: 100.0)
```

Comment: Than
cell.lbl.size.frame.height = height
like this?

Comment: how to combine two answers given by you

Comment: this one set the lable according to test and that set the cell accordong to text size

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSAttributedString` in `heightForRowAt` to calculate height for the row:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     let attString = NSAttributedString(string:"YOUR TEXT", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)])
     var r: CGRect = attString.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(self.tableView.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

     return r.size.height
}
```